# CSS Animation judder on Android Firefox Browser

Tags: css, firefox, mobile

I have a mobile search div on this website https://en.bentoandco.com/ that judders on load. This is what happens when clicking on the search icon https://vimeo.com/270001160 . The issue is only specific to Firefox on Android, I am not able to replicate it on the desktop version, not even if I select an Android mobile emulator.

This is my element

```
  <img src=" //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0029/8962/t/26/assets/icon-mobile-search.svg?8955747899599855085" class="js-mobile-search-open" id="mobile-search-icon" alt="Mobile search icon">

<div class="search-dropdown-mobile js-mobile-search-dropdown mobile-search-active">
  <span class="icon icon-x js-mobile-search-exit" id="mobile-search-exit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <div class="wrapper search-content">
    <form class="medium-down--show input-group search-bar" action="/search" method="get" role="search">
      <div class="one-whole search-grid-wrapper">
        <div id="mobile-search-flex" class="one-whole">
          <div class="search-input-field">
            <input id="searchInputMobile" name="q" value="" placeholder="Enter Search Terms..." class="input-group-field banner js-search-query aa-input" aria-label="Enter Search Terms..." autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" type="search"><pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: pre; font-family: &quot;Lato&quot;, &quot;HelveticaNeue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 500; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: optimizelegibility; text-transform: none;"></pre>
          </div>
          <div class="search-input-submit">
            <span class="input-group-btn banner">
              <button type="submit" id="mobile-submit-button" class="btn icon-fallback-text banner js-search-submit">
                <span id="mobile-submit-button-text">Search</span>
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS for it

```
.sticky-header.search-is-open {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    z-index: 9990;
}
.sticky-header {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;

.sticky-header .search-dropdown-mobile.mobile-search-active {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ececeb;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with elements in the past - usually due to using css transforms though. However, more often than not, using the CSS transform property `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` solves the problem. Something about using hardware acceleration I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will take a look at this and update the post.